# INTERVAL add i day is not working in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE DateInsert(
    DateInsert timestamp without time zone,
    DateInt integer NOT NULL
);
```

I want insert list day from 2018-01-01 to 2045-05-18 but it give me an erro

"invalid input syntax for type interval:"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertdate() RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE i integer := 0;
    d timestamp without time zone := '2018-01-01';
    di integer := 0;
BEGIN
    while i <10000
    LOOP
        d := d + INTERVAL ''+ i::character varying + ' day';
        di := to_char(d , 'yyyymmdd')::int;
        insert into DateInsert(DateInsert,DateInt) values(d, di); 
        i := i+1;
    END LOOP ;
    return i;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How can I insert to db with timestamp increase 1 in n day loop?

Code In sql server has been working.

```
declare @i int=0
declare @d datetime
declare @di int = 0
while @i <10000
    begin
    set @d = DATEADD(DAY, @i, '2018-01-01')
    set @di = cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @d, 112) as int)
    insert into DateInsert(DateInsert,DateInt) values(@d, @di)
    set @i = @i+1 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concatenation operator is `||` not `+`. And the prefixed form doesn't seem to like anything else than literals. But you can cast the concatenation expression.

So changing

```
...
d := d + INTERVAL ''+ i::character varying + ' day';
...
```

to

```
...
d := d + (i || ' day')::interval;
...
```

should work for you.